# Is there any trick to bounties?

Tags: genshin-impact

When I pick bounties in Genshin Impact, I seem to never be able to find the monster.

Like I will go through every square inch of the territory, or so I think, and will never seemingly find the monster.

So is there a trick I'm missing and thats why I never find them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In **Mondstadt** and **Liyue** you need to find multiple evidences before facing the actual bounty target. Use Elemental Sight to search for them - they could be either world objects like flowers or actual monsters you need to defeat before progressing the bounty.

In **Inazuma** it works differently: bounty targets appear as soon as you enter marked territory.

[source](https://genshin-impact.fandom.com/wiki/Bounties)